# How to use range.map in swift 3/4?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsrange

I have the code below, which works in swift 2.3. I am struggling to understand how to convert it to swift 3/4 - the issue it those is 
`Value of type 'Range<Int>' has no member 'map'`

```
let grainSize = CGFloat(0.01)
        let min = CGFloat(-3)
        let max = CGFloat(3)
        let range = Range<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: Int(min/grainSize), upper: Int(max/grainSize)))
        let lol = NSRange(range)

        var points = range.map { step -> CGPoint in
            let i = grainSize * CGFloat(step)
            let x = x_base + (i * controller.width / 4.0)
            let y = y_base + (m * equation(i))
            if x_init == CGFloat.max { x_init = x }
            return CGPointMake(x, y)
        }
        points.append(CGPointMake(x_init, y_base))
        points.forEach { renderer.lineTo($0) }
```

I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction for this - even to documentation regarding this, as I can't find anything about it in apple docs either =[

Comment: Compare https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Range` does not adopt `Sequence`, just create the range literally as `CountableClosedRange`

```
let range = Int(min/grainSize)...Int(max/grainSize)
```

Comment: This 100% worked. Thank you so much. Can you point me to some kind of documentation on this so I can understand a bit more about it?

Comment: Alternatively (no range needed): `var points = stride(from: min, through: max, by: grainSize).map { i in ... }`

Comment: @MartinR this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you